# Table is not reloading after AJAX success

Tags: jquery, laravel

I have a table of some records. I need to submit a form. When I submit the form I don't need to reload the page I only need to see the new data in that table with old records.  In success function I only echo a value of 1. If response is 1 then show success msg and load the new data with table.

Here is my code:

```
$("#cost_center").validate({
    rules: {          
        code: {
            required: true,
        },
        desc: {
            required:true,
        }
    },
    messages: {
        code : {
            required: "não pode ficar em branco"
        },
        desc : {
            required: "não pode ficar em branco"
        }
    },
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
        $(element).parents('.form-wrap').append(error);
    },
    submitHandler: function(form) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "{{ url('Organizer/AddCostCenter') }}",
            type: "POST",
            data: $('#cost_center').serialize(),
            success: function( response ) {
                if(response == 1){
                    $("form").trigger("reset");
                    // window.location.reload();
                    var successHtml = '<div class="alert alert-success">'+
                    '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>'+
                    '<strong><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign push-5-r"></</strong> '
                    +'Novos registros adicionados com sucesso ...'+
                    // + data.message +
                    '</div>';
                    $('.cost_msg').html(successHtml);
                    // var table =  $('#Cost_table').DataTable({ajax: "response.json"});
                    // table.ajax.reload(null, false);
                    $("a#step4").addClass('active show');
                    $('#tabs-1-4').addClass('show in active');
                    $('#tabs-1-4').show();
                    // $("#tabs-1-4").load(" #tabs-1-4 > *");
                }
            },
        });
    }
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="table-custom-responsive">
    <table id="Cost_table" class="table-custom table-custom-striped table-custom-primary" style="table-layout: fixed;width: 100%;">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Código</th>
                <th>Descrição</th>
                <th>Action</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach($centers as $cent)
            <tr id="cost_{{$cent->id}}">
                <td>{{$cent->code}}</td>
                <td>{{$cent->description}}</td>
                <td>
                    <a href="{{url('Organizer/Edit/Cost/Center/'.$cent->id)}}"><span class="schedule-classic-author-name" style="text-decoration: none;">Edit</span></a> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <a href="#"class="deleteCost" id="{{ $cent->id }}" data-token="{{ csrf_token() }}" ><span class="schedule-classic-author-name" style="text-decoration: none;">Remove</span></a>
                </td>
            </tr>
            @endforeach
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Please post the example table also to make your question more clear

Comment: Is `response` really 1? What does your browser devtools show? Check the network tab, check the response from the server.  Your success function tries to update 4 elements (`. cost_msg`, `#step4`, `#tabs...` etc) but none of them appear in your HTML.

Comment: And of course - is your validation actually passing?  Does your AJAX really fire?  Check browser devtools, do you see your POST actually happening?

Comment: ... ? If you have solved this problem, either post the answer if it might help others, or delete the question if not.  If you have not solved it, describe the results of your debugging as requested.